# How many elements are the same in two lists (haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I try to learn how many elements are the same in the given two sets. To be clear,

```
let a = ["t","k","m"]
let b = ["k","b","t","c"]
```

"t" and "k" are parts of both lists, so the return will be 2. How can I implement like this function without using any library and using recursion?

Comment: Should it deal with duplicates?

Comment: ...or do you basically consider lists as _sets_? (There's [a better type for those](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Set.html).)

Comment: @Shoe there will be no duplicated element, so it should not.

Comment: What kind of libraries are you not allowed to use or don't want to use? You should probably specify that in the question.

Comment: @Shoe I will not use any library. I try to implement using recursion.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @Shoe i uploaded here. http://prntscr.com/aih6mc
Actually, I have to use one more recursion for y:ys but I could not do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not our job to do your homework. Non-working code should be included in the body of the question, with an explanation of what it should do and what it's doing instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module `Data.Set` to convert the two lists to sets and calculate the size of the intersection:

```
let a = Set.fromList ["t","k","m"]
let b = Set.fromList ["k","b","t","c"]
print $ Set.size (a `Set.intersection` b)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6b2d928f565bab7)

As a general rule, if the order of the elements in the list doesn't matter and the list doesn't contain duplicates it's a good idea to convert it into a `Set`.

---

For some reason you don't want to use the standard library. If you don't care about algorithmic complexity you can then use:

```
length $ Prelude.filter (`elem` b) a
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd44125f8e4376b3)

of if you want it to be put into recursive form, then it's something like this:

```
countDuplicates :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
countDuplicates [] b = 0
countDuplicates (x:rest) b =
    let index = if x `elem` b then 1 else 0
    in index + countDuplicates rest b
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2da061682842fb54)

which if you don't want to use `elem` either will be further expanded to:

```
countDuplicates :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
countDuplicates [] b = 0
countDuplicates (x:rest) b =
    let myElem a [] = False
        myElem a (al:lst) = if a == al then True else myElem a lst
        index = if x `myElem` b then 1 else 0
    in index + countDuplicates rest b
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0fa1fe64d137a66)

Comment: Thank you for response, but I dont want to use any library. I want to implement without using module. I try to do that using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any extra functions you can write it simply as follows

```
countIntersect :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
countIntersect _ [] = 0
countIntersect [] _ = 0
countIntersect (x:xs) y'@(y:ys) | x==y = 1 + countIntersect xs ys
                                | otherwise = countIntersect [x] ys + countIntersect xs y'
```

essentially, the way you would do by hand, compare the first two elements if same increase the counter and move the next element in both list.  If not equal compare the first element of the first list with the rest of second list and remainder of the first list to the second list.